# htaccess: Prevent 301 redirect appending / to the end of the URL for subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, mod-dir

I defined this `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Disable http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Disable www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# /random run random.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Redirect /index.html in URL to /
RewriteRule (.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect xxx.html in URL to nach xxx
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
```

I have this folder structure:

- root

  - `index.html`
  - `about.html`
  - `example` (directory)

    - `index.html`
    - `x.html`

It works fine for:

- Main page is `x.com`
- `x.com/about` returns the file content of `/about.html`
- `x.com/about.html` redirects to `x.com/about`
- `x.com/example/x` returns the file content of `/example/x.html`
- `x.com/example/` returns the file content of `/example/index.html`

But this happens also and I want to disallow this:

- `x.com/example` redirects to `x.com/example/`
- `x.com/example` should return the file content of `/example/index.html`

Do you have an idea what I have to change in my `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `x.com/example` redirect to `x.com/example/`

Since `/example` is a physical directory, mod_dir "fixes" the URL and appends the trailing slash with a 301 (permanent) redirect. The trailing slash is *required* in order to server the `DirectoryIndex` (ie. `index.html` in this case) from that directory.

However, we can prevent mod_dir from appending the trailing slash with the `DirectorySlash Off` directive. BUT, we must then issue an internal rewrite to append the trailing slash otherwise the `DirectoryIndex` document will not be served (as mentioned above). (Or, we could rewrite directly to the index document.)

When setting `DirectorySlash Off` we must also ensure that directory-listings (mod_autoindex) are disabled, since the presence of an index document in that directory will no longer prevent the directory listing.

To resolve potential canonicalisation issues you now need to "redirect" in the other direction to remove any trailing slash on the requested URL. eg. requests to `/example/` now need to be redirected back to `/example`.

In addition, the following rule that rewrites to the corresponding `.html` file is not strictly correct:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
> RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [NC,L]
> ```

The *condition* (that uses `REQUEST_FILENAME`) is not necessarily testing the same URL that you are ultimately rewriting to in the *substitution* (that uses `REQUEST_URI`). So, in certain scenarios (eg. when requesting a non-existent file in a directory that also happens to map to a `.html` file) you can get a rewrite loop (500 internal server error). See the following question/answer on ServerFault that goes into more detail on this: https://serverfault.com/questions/989333/using-apache-rewrite-rules-in-htaccess-to-remove-html-causing-a-500-error

The same applies to the earlier rule that appends the `.php` extension.

Bringing the above points together, we get the following:

```
# [NEW] Directory listing (mod_autoindex) must be disabled
Options -Indexes

# [NEW] Prevent mod_dir appending the trailing slash
DirectorySlash Off

RewriteEngine On

# Disable http
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Disable www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect /index.html in URL to /
RewriteRule (.*)index\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect xxx.html in URL to just xxx
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.?]+)\.html [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]

# [NEW] Redirect to remove trailing slash on direct requests
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule (.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]

# [NEW] Internal rewrite to append trailing slash to directories
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1 -d
RewriteRule (.+) $1/ [L]

# /random run random.php
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [L]

# Append ".html" if corresponding file exists
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
```

The new rules related to your immediate issue are indicated with `[NEW]`.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing since the 301 (permanent) redirect that appended the trailing slash will have been cached. Test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

Additional notes:

- There's no point testing that the request does not map to a file before testing that the same request plus `.php` *does* map to a file, these are mutually exclusive events, particularly since your `RewriteRule` *pattern* excludes dots (so excludes URLs with file extensions), so I have removed that *condition*.
- No need to backslash-escape literal dots in the `RewriteCond` *TestString* since this is an "ordinary" string, not a regex.
- No need for the `NC` flag on two of the `RewriteRule` directives since the regex already matches a-z and A-Z.
- I grouped the canonical redirects *before* the internal rewrites.

> ```
> # Redirect xxx.html in URL to nach xxx
> RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /([^.]+)\.html [NC]
> RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
> ```

Note that I also modified the regex in the *condition* of this rule to avoid matching a potential query string, otherwise a request of the form `/foo.html?bar.html` would result in a double redirect and the query string would be corrupted.

NB: You don't currently have a corresponding rule for `.php` requests. (You could handle both in the same rule.)